# Kernel patches with Bitbake

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm using a embedded linux on a SOM module, based on IMX6. 
I would like to patch my kernel,it works fine, it has been patched, but i would like to add some features.
I apply the old patches on the sources, and add my code, and create a new patch.

In yocto I add my patch to the recipe and bitbake it, I start the board with the new loaded kernel, and it seems it does not have my modification!

For bitbake my new kernel, I type :

```
bitbake -c clean linux-toradex-fsl
bitbake linux-toradex-fsl
```

It compiles without any errors, I copy my uImage in my tftp folder, but my features do not seems to be executed.

So I try to create a simple patch, with

```
printk(KERN_WARNING"This is a test\n");
```

I place it after another warning, called and displayed.

And it does not work either.

I check with `-c devshell` and my modification are applied in yocto, the patch works here.

I also check the uImage file, it has the same size, with or without my patches.

Do you have some ideas for this issue?

Regards,
Pierre-Olivier

## Solution

I found the solution after some tries, I just need to run

```
bitbake -c cleansstate linux-toradex-fsl
bitbake my-image
```

And the image is bitbaked with the patched kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Bitbake is funny about -clean.  It tries to keep a state directory, so -clean just runs the normal "clean" in the makefile, but the makefile can be short-circuited by the shared state, which can include zipped up prebuilt binaries from a previous build.  Try this:

```
bitbake -c cleansstate linux-toradex-fsl
bitbake linux-toradex-fsl
```

note the extra 's' in cleansstate (clean shared state).

Comment: I tried, but it is the same as before, my printk does not appear at booting.

Comment: Hmmm, that's what works for me, but you can try hitting it with a bigger hammer:  run -c cleanall, -c cleansstate, and -c clean.  
Then run -c fetch, then -c configure
Then check the build tree - under the work folder there is arch folder and under there will be the actual linux build folder.  Check and see if the patch is present and applied.

Comment: I found the solution, i simply do a cleansstate, and instead of building the kernel, i build an image, and the right kernel is rebuilt

Comment: When you were building just the kernel, where were you retrieving the kernel from?  The deploy folder?

Comment: I retrieve my sources from a git repository